# how can I update texlive 2015

Tags: texlive, windows, update

How can I update my TeXlive( 2015) to newest one(2018).
Is it necessary for me to update Biditexmaker or  update TeXlive just?

Comment: Is `Biditexmaker` an editor? If yes it should be enough to install texlive2018. If the installation of texlive2018 was successful, you can delete texlive2015 afterwards.

Comment: yes it is, ok just it is  enough ? I hope it workes, thanks alot

Comment: What operating system do you use?